# How to declare object with different name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, declare

Let's say i declaring an object

```
let Mahasiswa = {
    name: "Steve",
    age: 22
}
```

And then later in my code i copy these code with same name;

```
let {name, age} = Mahasiswa;
console.log(name, age) // Steve 22
```

but how do i change it to different variable name?

```
let {name as Player, age as ID} = Mahasiswa;
console.log(Player, ID) // Steve 22
```

Comment: No, this is JS--the `as` is just pseudocode to indicate what OP is trying to achieve with a rename.

Answer (score 2):

We use `:`

```js
let Mahasiswa = {
  name: "Steve",
  age: 22
}

let {
  name: Player,
  age: ID
} = Mahasiswa;

console.log({ Player, ID });
```